# Can't understand the code example in xcode

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xcode, xamarin

I'm trying to convert code from swift xcode to c# (xamarin). I don't understand the following code:

```
#pragma mark - Implement DTBackgroundView Class

@interface DTBackgroundView : UIView
{
    UIWindow *_previousKeyWindow;
    UIWindow *_alertWindow;
    NSMutableArray *_alertViews;
}

+ (Instancetype)currentBackground;

static DTBackgroundView *singletion = nil;

@implementation DTBackgroundView

+ (Instancetype)currentBackground
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        singletion = [DTBackgroundView new];
    });

    return singletion;
}
```

---

My questions are:

1. What is who is **currentBackground**?
2. What is **backgroundView** in the following code:

```
DTBackgroundView *backgroundView = [DTBackgroundView currentBackground];
```

Comment: You need to consult a __designPatterns__ book to to get an idea of __singleton__ class. And the code you have posted is not in __Swift__ its __Objective-C__.

Answer (score 2):

As Adeel says in his comment, that's Objective-C code, not Swift. You've posted the implementation of the `DTBackgroundView` class.

The `currentBackground` method is a class method (or "static method" as it's called in C++) that you use to request a singleton instance of the class. If the singleton has already been created, that method returns it. If not, it creates the singleton and returns it.

You should read up on the singleton design pattern and use whatever the convention is for creating singletons in C#.

I wouldn't worry too much about trying to do a line-by-line conversion of that code - it uses [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch), (Grand Central Dispatch) which is specific to Cocoa (iOS and Mac OS).  Just find the C# convention for creating and returning singletons and use that.

Comment: Can you expand on the acronym GCD? Readers (like myself) may not be familiar with it.

Comment: Google is your friend. GCD stands for Grand Central Dispatch. There's a wiki article on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch

Comment: Agreed, Google is my friend (quickly learnt what it was) but thought it could be useful being nested into the answer :)